# Address lookup after filter

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google form and a spreadsheet that is supposed to process it. The spreadsheet needs to filter the responses by date and get their respective data after that.

E.g. Consider:

[image: example table]

With the columns being A and B and the rows being 1-4.

How do I filter it by month in ascending order followed by adding the amount next to it?

So it would look something like:
[image: processed table]

I understand how to filter by month in ascending order. It is done using `=SORT(FILTER(A:A, MONTH(A:A)=1))` (for Jan). But how do you get the data next to it? I have tried `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(SORT(FILTER(A:A, MONTH(A:A)=1)), 2))` but there is no error and it is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do SORT for whole A:B instead of doing only for A:A.

Eg:

`SORT(FILTER(A:B, MONTH(A:A)=1),1,TRUE)` for Jan

`SORT(FILTER(A:B, MONTH(A:A)=2),1,TRUE)` for Feb

Please refer link [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QgUcwQZsxG0-MK0C4A1VZnL3NnE6H-ai85pjnUH7Ps8/edit#gid=0) and see whether this is what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
=QUERY(A:B,"select month(A), A, sum(B) where not A is null group by month(A), A")
```

or this:

```
=QUERY(A:B,"select day(A), sum(B) where not A is null group by day(A) pivot month(A)")
```

---

or you could use your formula `=SORT(FILTER(A:A, MONTH(A:A)=1))` twice and use [custom date format](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?hl=en) for first column to label it as JAN, FEB...